# pyspark udf on large data

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe with 10 million rows and only 3 columns. One of the column is of MapType() containing map of date, value. So, that column contains timeseries data and each row contains a time series. Hence, I have 10 million timeseries in that dataframe.

I have custom code/function written in Python to detect spike in the timeseries data and am using pyspark udf to use that function to detect spike on each timeseries in the dataframe. In side my spike detection function that MapType() object is converted to pandas dataframe and I use pandas mean and std. deviation to detect spike.

pyspark udf is costly. This is taking about 90 mins for 10 million rows.

Do we have some other alternative?
If udf is the only choice, how can we improve the performance? Please note that I cannot use spark2.3/pandas_udf and I am limited to spark2.2.

Comment: What makes you think that udf is the issue?

Comment: If you are worried about performance try to use native pyspark functions as much as possible.  Having example data would be helpful, but one potential workaround would be to use pyspark's `explode()` function on your time series column then do a `groupby` on the date column and utilize pyspark's `mean` and `stddev` functions.

Comment: @vealkind In 2.2 explode can have exponential complexity and operations which on order (like time series) are rarely efficient (window functions and such).

Comment: @user9613318 as per my understanding, python udf are not efficient as serialisation deserialisation steps are involved from JVM to Python and vice versa.

Comment: That's true, but it is not necessarily the source of the problem. How long does it take to run the pipeline if you omit `udf` part? How long does it take to run function used in `udf` on average record?

Comment: @vealkind Have to check the performance after using explode. One of the problem is spike detection is just one such example. I have other functions where statsmodels and scikit-learn libs are used. Explode will probably not help.